# How a friend function of a base class is calling the overridden virtual function of derived class even though they are private ?(C++)

Tags: c++, oop

**My code-**

```
class base{
private:
     virtual void print(){
        cout<<" from base"<<endl;
    }
    friend void show(base &obj);
};
class drived1 : public base{
private:
    void print(){
        cout<<" from drived1"<<endl;
    }
};
class drived2 : public base{
private:
    void print(){
        cout<<" from drived2"<<endl;
    }
};
void show(base &obj){
    obj.print();
}

int main() {
    base b;
    drived1 d1;
    drived2 d2;
    
    show(b);
    show(d1);
    show(d2);
}
```

**Output:**
`from base`
`from drived1` *//* *print function form derived class is called, though it is private*.
`from drived2` *//* *print function form derived class is called, though it is private*.

`show(base &obj)` is a friend function of base class, but how it is calling the private method from derived class?

Comment: It is not calling the private method from delivered class, it is calling a virtual overridden method of the friend class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how C++ works. *Access specifiers* (`public`, `private`, and `protected`) depend on the static type of your variable, not the dynamic type. In your example, when

```
void show(base &obj){
    obj.print();
}
```

is compiled, the compiler does not know that the function will be invoked with a `drived1` argument. It knows that `obj` is of type `base&`, so it only checks whether it can invoke `base::print()` - which it can because it is a `friend` of `base`.

Comment: That means access specifiers are checked only during the `compile time`. But because of using the `virtual` keyword, `late binding` occurs and during `run time` access specifiers are not checked and the methods were called without any error.

Answer (score 1):

It is calling the private method from derived class because the derived class is being implicitly converted to `base` class when you call the function.

So, you have an object of type `drived1`.
Then you pass it to the function show(base&).

The object is being upcasted to base.
Then, in the function show(base&) you use the virtual function print().

The function called is the `drived1::print()` member function thanks to the way C++ polymorphic behavior works. (A class is called polymorphic if it contains virtual functions).

This function is called and you get output `from drived1`.